# What does * mean in git rev-list?

Tags: git

Just for context, I've got a Git repo with a number of remotes, some of which I consider less important and put in a subgroup by prepending them with a group name and a slash. For example, I might have `origin`, `othercomputer` as my "main" remotes; and `otherpeople/alice`, `otherpeople/bob` as secondary remotes that I just check in on occasionally. I was looking for a simple way to make `gitk` only list branches in my main remotes (since `gitk --all` lists everything).

Just as a random thing, I tried running `gitk \*`, and frankly to my surprise, it seems to have done exactly what I was looking for (displaying my local branches and my "main" remotes), so I tried to figure out what it actually does. Since the arguments to `gitk` are mostly the same as those to `git rev-list`, I've been trying to read that manpage in order to do that, but I can't find anything.

So, what does `gitk \*` do, and where is this documented? (I assume that it is documented, since Git documentation is generally quite excellent.)

(Just to avoid confusion, the backslash in `\*` is the shell escape to pass the asterisk unmodified to `gitk`. I did not mean to imply that I'm actually passing that backslash to `gitk`.)

Comment: Side note: gitk is not part of core Git (see the HISTORY section of the man page).

Comment: But note that [`gitk` is included in the sources if git](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/gitk-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gitk *` (with the star quoted from the shell) causes `gitk` to run:

```
git log --no-color -z --pretty=raw --show-notes --parents --boundary <hash> -- *
```

where the `<hash>` here is that from `HEAD`.  (Your version of `gitk` might actually run `git rev-list`; mine has `proc start_rev_list` defined at line 358, which then runs `git log`, not `git rev-list`, at line 415.  Note that gitk is a tcl script and hence easy to read.)

This `*`, being after the `--` separator, acts as a *pathspec*.  It turns on History Simplification while selecting all paths.

> I was looking for a simple way to make gitk only list branches in my main remotes ...

The gitk parser understands (to some extent) the `--remotes=` arguments that `git log` and `git rev-list` allow.  Unfortunately, I think there's no really good way to match the ones that *don't* have a slash in them here.  The "right" `git log` argument is `--exclude` and the gitk code has no handler for that (but you could add one).

Comment: Right, I might have just imagined that it included the remotes I wanted and excluded the ones I didn't want just because those were the ones I saw, while in fact they were just displayed because they were part of the history of my `HEAD`. That makes sense, and I guess my question was less valid than I thought since it never was a `rev-list` argument.

Comment: Also yes, I had already found `--exclude`. I was just quite curious what `*` was supposed to do.